# Rails: Programmatic Youtube Video embeds not rendering in mobile

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, youtube

Here's the site: http://www.trailerpuppy.com/

I've used the tutorial from [this](http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/) site to load images that look like youtube videos instead of the videos themselves (to load quicker). When the image is clicked, JS swaps the image for a youtube video and auto-plays.

Works like a charm on a desktop, but for some reason the videos are not displaying on mobile (no image or video is loaded) and I have no idea how to troubleshoot without chrome dev tools.

Here's the code that renders the vids:

```
<div class="youtube-container">
         <div class="youtube-player" <%= "data-id=#{trailer.youtube_id}" %>></div>
      </div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function(){

    (function() {
        var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
        for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            var p = document.createElement("div");
            p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
            p.onclick = labnolIframe;
            v[n].appendChild(p);
        }
    })();


    });



    function labnolThumb(id) {
        return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
    }

    function labnolIframe() {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");
        iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you connect your android to your computer with usb debugging enabled you can use chrome dev tools remotely with your phone.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en